# Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is invalid XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

I'm trying to put a datetimepicker in my Rails 4 app. I decided to try this one: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker.

The instructions are relatively straightforward, but when I load the page, I get the following JS error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is   invalid XML, and therefore cannot be inserted into an XML document.
```

If I pause on the line where this is happening in JQuery.extend.buildfragment:

```
tmp.innerHTML = wrap[1] + elem.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" ) + wrap[2];
```

I see that it's trying to set innerHTML to this:

```
<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget dropdown-menu"><div class="datepicker"><div class="datepicker-days"><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">&lsaquo;</th><th colspan="5" class="picker-switch"></th><th class="next">&rsaquo;</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-months"><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">&lsaquo;</th><th colspan="5" class="picker-switch"></th><th class="next">&rsaquo;</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-years"><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">&lsaquo;</th><th colspan="5" class="picker-switch"></th><th class="next">&rsaquo;</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
```

Most XML validators complain about the `&lsaquo;` value being invalid. However, I don't have control over how this string is constructed since this is internal in jquery. I know that the datetimepicker works for most people without any issues, so this seems to be something wrong in my environment.

Comment: Why are you using an xml validator?

Comment: @epascarello The error message is telling me that the markup is "invalid XML", so I was curious to find out what about the markup that JQuery was trying to insert might be considered invalid. Just using it to try and debug the issue.

Comment: @Kohanz what is your `<!DOCTYPE>`? You're working with XML I guess?

Comment: @Pointy HTML. This error occurs on an HTML page in a rails app in the JS code that is trying to initialize the datepicker control.

Comment: Well if it's giving you an error about XML, then something is amiss.

Comment: @Pointy Agreed, which brings me here :)

Comment: In Firefox, there's a "View page info" entry in the right-button page menu. That should document type and the render mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68359/discussion-between-kohanz-and-pointy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the page was being served up as XHTML+XML, rather than HTML (credit to @Pointy for pointing this out).

I found that in my application_controller.rb, there was a line as follows:

```
  before_filter{ response.content_type = 'application/xhtml+xml' }
```

I don't actually know why this line was present, but removing this line solved the issue and has allowd me to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

XHTML does not support `document.write` or `.innerHTML`. Due to the fact, that jQuery inserts the new code using one of these methods, all XHTML compatible browsers will error out.

XHTML with `application/xhtml+xml` does not support raw modification of the source using any of these jQuery methods: `.append()`, `.html()`, `.insert...()`, etc.

Instead, query for some JSON data and insert the AJAX-received values into either pre-defined tags using `.text()` / `.val()` or dynamically create those nodes using `document.createElement('someTag')`.

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite