# Will exception occur when assigning innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

I read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML, which claims `SyntaxError` may happen.

```
dom = document.createElement('div')
// output: <div></div>
dom.innerHTML = '[try.various.strings.here]'
// output: "[try.various.strings.here]"
dom
// check final DOM
```

I have tried to replace test string with `<div>` (partial), `<div` (broken) and `<div></p>` (unmatched). Never have I met exception. I wonder whether I need to add pre-check or protection (`try..catch`) for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

The specifications say it can if the browser wants it to, but I don't think any major browser does so **for HTML** (well, I wouldn't make any guarantees about IE9-IE11 and certain element types, actually). (Whereas they **do** for XML.) From the definition of an HTML parser in the [HTML 5.2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#html-parser):

> This specification defines the parsing rules for HTML documents, whether they are syntactically correct or not. Certain points in the parsing algorithm are said to be parse errors. The error handling for parse errors is well-defined (that’s the processing rules described throughout this specification), **but user agents, while parsing an HTML document, may abort the parser at the first parse error that they encounter for which they do not wish to apply the rules described in this specification.**

*(my emphasis)*

### Details

The [DOM Parsing and Serialization spec](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#extensions-to-the-element-interface) defines `innerHTML`, and says:

> On setting, these steps must be run:
>
> 1. Let *fragment* be the result of invoking the [fragment parsing algorithm](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dfn-fragment-parsing-algorithm) with the new value as *markup*, and the context object as the *context element*.
> 2. If the context object is a template element, then let context object be the template's template contents (a DocumentFragment).
> 3. Replace all with fragment within the context object.

If we follow the *fragment parsing algorithm* link, we get to:

> The following steps form the fragment parsing algorithm, whose arguments are a *markup* string and a *context element*:
>
> 1. If the *context element*'s node document is an HTML document: let algorithm be the [HTML fragment parsing algorithm](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dfn-html-fragment-parsing-algorithm).
>      
>    If the *context element*'s node document is an XML document: let algorithm be the [XML fragment parsing algorithm](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dfn-xml-fragment-parsing-algorithm).
> 2. Let *new children* be the result of invoking *algorithm* with *markup* as the input, and *context element* as the context element.
> 3. Let *fragment* be a new DocumentFragment whose node document is *context element*'s node document.
> 4. Append each Node in *new children* to *fragment* (in tree order).
> 5. Return the value of *fragment*.

If we follow the *HTML parsing algorithm* link above, we get steps creating and using an HTML parser. If we follow the link to the definition of an HTML parser, we get the first link in **TL;DR** above and the text quoted above.

Comment: Could you give an example for HTML to let it crash when innerHTML being assigned?

Comment: @MoYummy - As I said above: *"...but I don't think any major browser does so for HTML."*

Answer (score 0):

Errors can occur.

Basically, it depends on the content type and how it is served by the browser.

In traditional cases it will not throw an error, but in some edge cases such as [Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is invalid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824609/uncaught-syntaxerror-failed-to-set-the-innerhtml-property-on-element-the-p) or as can be seen in [this bug report](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/724), the error will be triggered.

Better wrap it in a `try..catch` statement.

Comment: Though, that's only XML, not ordinary HTML.

Comment: Could you give an example for HTML to let it crash when `innerHTML` being assigned?